# How do I overflow-y: scroll in the child of an overflow-x: scroll

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I have the following markup and css:

https://jsfiddle.net/f0u9kpkb/

The key section is:

```
.grid {
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 200px;
}

.grid .grid-body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I would expect my code to produce a horizontal scrollbar on the outer div, and a vertical scrollbar on the inner div (on overflow), but in the example I get 2 horizontal scrollbars (despite setting overflow-x: visible on the inner scroll bar)

Is there a way to achieve the effect I am looking for

Comment: Not sure does I understand well https://jsfiddle.net/14t2cdpr/1/

Comment: react-data-grid uses a javascript solution for this problem - maybe this is the only way.

Comment: The only solution I can find is to scroll the body, then use the onscroll event to keep the headers at the same position

Answer (score 0):

Please review the [overflow property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) on w3schools.com

You have a couple of issues I can see going on here. The first is you may need to add more rows to your table to make it longer so that it actually scrolls (it didn't on my monitor).

The second is you are defining *overflow* properties for  the *.grid* class twice.

Once here:

```
.grid {
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
```

But then you have this class:

```
.grid .grid-body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

which changes the properties for not only the *.grid-body* class but also the *.grid* class

I removed the overflow properties from this class and added another style for the *.grid-body* class only so it doesn't override the *.grid* class properties.

```
.grid-body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

I also added more rows to your table. This achieves your requested behavior of a vertical scroll on the inner div and a horizontal div on the outer div. [See my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0u9kpkb/1/).

You may want to play with the way it looks.  I recommend setting the outer divs overflow to `overflow: auto` and the inner divs overflow to `overflow: visible` like I did in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0u9kpkb/3/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - unfortunately the inner div (.grid-body) clips at the edge of the parent width, rather than rendering in the overflow area (that can be scrolled into view).

Comment: I updated my answer.  I was just showing you how to get the divs to function the way you asked (vertical scrollbar on inner div and horizontal scrollbar on outer div).  You should be able to adjust them for your own design prefrences.

Comment: Hi Trapline, thanks for the help, the current jsfiddle scrolls the headers as well as the content, it's keeping the headers in place that I am finding especially difficult

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `right:0` CSS to `.grid .grid-body` Class

And

Added a new class `.fix-position{
  top:auto;
  position:fixed;
}`

Please review my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vatsal18/f0u9kpkb/5/)

Please let me know, if there is any issue.

Comment: Thank's for the answer vatsal, I need to keep the headers at the top even when scrolling vertically (but they should scroll horizontally)